# Can you explain this code for me - I can't understand it well?

Tags: assembly, dos, masm, x86-16

```
MODEL SMALL
  .DATA
    MSG  DB  0DH,0AH, ' ENTER THE STRING :-----> :  $'
    MSG2 DB  0DH,0AH, ' YOUR STRING IS  :-----> :  $'
    STR1 DB  255 DUP(?)
    ONE  DB ?
    TWO  DB ?
  .CODE
BEGIN:
  MOV AX,@DATA
  MOV DS,AX

  LEA DX,MSG
  MOV AH,09H
  INT 21H
  LEA SI,STR1
  MOV AH,01H

READ:
  INT 21H
  MOV BL,AL

  CMP AL,0DH
  JE  DISPLAY

  XOR AL,20H
  MOV [SI],AL
  INC SI

  ;CMP BL,0DH
  JMP READ

DISPLAY:
  MOV AL,'$'
  MOV [SI],AL

  LEA DX,MSG2
  MOV AH,09H
  INT 21H

  LEA DX,STR1
  MOV AH,09H
  INT 21H

 ; MOV AH,4CH
 ; INT 21H
  .EXIT
END BEGIN
```

This code is supposed to change lower case letters of a string to upper case letters, but I do not understand it...

Comment: Which part do you have trouble with? I will guess and say it's the `XOR AL,20H` which actually does the mapping. If you look at an ascii table, you will see you only need to flip that one bit to convert, and xor can do that for you.

Answer (score 3):

the part that's doing the convert is "hidden" in the entry-loop

```
  MOV AH,01H
READ:
  INT 21H            ; DOS 21h/01h reads char from stdin
  MOV BL,AL          

  CMP AL,0DH         ; exit loop if Enter was pressed 
  JE  DISPLAY

  XOR AL,20H         ; <-- here the case is switched, in ascii
                     ;     Bit 0x20 defines upper/lowercase

  MOV [SI],AL        ; store converted byte in output string
  INC SI

  ;CMP BL,0DH
  JMP READ           ; perform the loop
```

ps: you have an issue in this loop, it's converting everything that's been entered, even if it's not a letter

Comment: Let's hope everybody reads the "ps:". It's the most important part of the answer.